# Return Same Row Twice if Both 'OR' Conditions Are True

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting to run an SQL query to display the results of a set of fights in a competition.
Fight details are stored in the fields fighter1, fighter2 and winner.
What I need to do is put together a list of all fights, with each fight appearing twice in the list - once with, for example

```
Competitor:fighter1, Opponent:fighter2, Winner:fighter1
```

and also, elsewhere in the list

```
Competitor:fighter2, Opponent:fighter1, Winner:fighter1
```

I've been using an sql union to pull the details from each fight twice, and trying to assign different aliases to the fighter1 and fighter2 columns to swap them around, but i'm not even sure if this is possible.

My query is like this (with unnecessary stuff from other tables omitted)

```
SELECT wp_ema_fights.fighter1 AS competitor,
wp_ema_fights.fighter2 AS opponent, 
wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM wp_ema_fights
UNION ALL
SELECT wp_ema_fights.fighter1 AS opponent,
wp_ema_fights.fighter2 AS competitor,   
wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM wp_ema_fights
ORDER BY competitor
```

This query is displaying each fight twice, but like this:

```
Competitor:fighter1, Opponent:fighter2, Winner:fighter1
Competitor:fighter1, Opponent:fighter2, Winner:fighter1
```

Has anyone got any idea how I can swap the two around and order the list by whichever fighter has been assigned as 'competitor' each time??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT   wp_ema_fights.fighter1 AS competitor,
         wp_ema_fights.fighter2 AS opponent,
         wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM     wp_ema_fights
UNION ALL
SELECT   wp_ema_fights.fighter2 AS competitor,
         wp_ema_fights.fighter1 AS opponent,
         wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM     wp_ema_fights
ORDER BY competitor
```

Comment: +1 : Don't move the fields in the SELECT statement around, keep them in the same order in ***both*** SELECT statements.

Comment: Thanks a mil! That's doing what I need now.

Answer (score 1):

As well as Xophmester's answer, you can do it with a join instead of a UNION.  This has the advantage of only loading the source data once rather than twice.  (Which is more relevant for very large data sets rather than just small ones.)

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN Mode.ID = 1 THEN wp_ema_fights.fighter1 ELSE wp_ema_fights.fighter2 END AS competitor,
         CASE WHEN Mode.ID = 2 THEN wp_ema_fights.fighter2 ELSE wp_ema_fights.fighter1 END AS opponent,
         wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM     wp_ema_fights
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 as ID UNION ALL SELECT 2 as ID) AS Mode
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Mode.ID = 1 THEN wp_ema_fights.fighter1 ELSE wp_ema_fights.fighter2 END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `UNION` will ignore the mismatched column names and order the columns simply based on the order in which they appear in the two `SELECT` statements.

So, just swap around `.fighter1` and `.fighter2` in the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT wp_ema_fights.fighter1 AS competitor,
wp_ema_fights.fighter2 AS opponent, 
wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM wp_ema_fights
UNION ALL
SELECT wp_ema_fights.fighter2 AS competitor,
wp_ema_fights.fighter1 AS opponent,   
wp_ema_fights.winner AS winner
FROM wp_ema_fights
ORDER BY competitor
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL product supports it, change `UNION ALL` to `UNION CORRESPONDING`.